# Linux Mint 18.3 XFCE Open File Dialog specify file/folder path via Textbox by default instead of GUI

Tags: linux-mint, xfce, gtk

In the 'Open File' Dialog box, is there a way to specify the default file/folder path via Textbox instead of GUI?

Ex. /somefolder/somefile.png

Ideally, I would be able to copy/paste the above example in a Textbox, and that would be the file that the Dialog uses.

[image]

If you need a way to see this dialog, and you are logged into Linux Mint, Press **Ctrl+O** in an application.

I just found [this](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=228465#p1207193)........

> If you are in the file open dialog, press ctrl-L, this changes the address bar to the way you want it to be.

**How do I make the path bar a text field by default**?

> In the dconf editor, I find an option to change org.gtk.Settings.FileChooser (capitalization included in original description shown in dconf editor) > location-mode from "path-bar" to "filename-entry". Unfortunately, it has no effect, and as soon as I use a program that should be using this option, it pops back to "path-bar".

The above doesn't seem to work, looks like the proper setting.

This is a GTK+ Dialog.  Here is a [Post](https://superuser.com/questions/944119/replace-gtk-file-dialog-with-alternative) that talks about replacing GTK+ dialog with another.

Here is a grunt way of setting the default through a sh script:

```
#!/bin/bash
string="Attach File(s)"
string2="Open Files"
string3="Open File"
while :;
do

    while :;
    do
        exitcondition=$(wmctrl -l | grep "$string")
        exitcondition2=$(wmctrl -l | grep "$string2")
        exitcondition3=$(wmctrl -l | grep "$string3")
        if [ "$exitcondition" != "" ]; then
                whichcondition=1
                break
        fi
        if [ "$exitcondition2" != "" ]; then
                whichcondition=2
                break
        fi
        if [ "$exitcondition3" != "" ]; then
                whichcondition=3
                break
        fi
        sleep .2
    done
    xdotool keydown ctrl key l keyup ctrl
    while :;
    do
        if [ "$whichcondition" = 1 ]; then
                exitcondition=$(wmctrl -l | grep "$string")
                if [ "$exitcondition" == "" ]; then
                        break
                fi
        fi
        if [ "$whichcondition" = 2 ]; then
                exitcondition2=$(wmctrl -l | grep "$string2")
                if [ "$exitcondition2" == "" ]; then
                        break
                fi
        fi
        if [ "$whichcondition" = 3 ]; then
                exitcondition3=$(wmctrl -l | grep "$string3")
                if [ "$exitcondition3" == "" ]; then
                        break
                fi
        fi
        sleep .2
    done
done
```

The above is an answer that works, but has a problem that it can trigger on a window that it is not suppose to.

Comment: Why did you delete your answer? Did it not work?

Comment: I see that the text from the deleted answer is now in the question. Is it an answer or a question. I really can't work out what is the question, and what it you trying to answer.

Comment: It doesn't work.

Comment: @conrad be more specific.  You have to make sure wmctrl and xdotool are installed on your machine.  You also have to make sure your script has execute permission:  chmod +x script.sh  This was tested on Linux Mint worked just fine.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor, the question is: How to get a textbox to specify path by default.  Ctrl+L is how you do it (but not by default).  The answer is deleted because Its not the answer I was looking for.  I want the textbox to be the default instead of GUI.

Comment: It doesn't work in the sense that it's not a robust solution to have a shell script polling for windows every 200 milliseconds and randomly inserting keypresses into matching X programs.  This is a fantastic hack (kudos!  It is clever) around a GNOME bug where GNOME refuses to provide choices to powerusers, but it doesn't really solve the problem.  You noted "[it] has a problem that it can trigger on a window that it is not suppose to," which is a major drawback.  Also, the Ctrl+L sequence doesn't work on the save file dialogue from Evince, for whatever reason (even pressed manually).

Comment: @ConradMeyer I agree, its not the best solution, which is why its not in the answer section.  I'm still waiting for a real answer.  Your also right CTRL+L doesn't work for the 'Save As' dialog box.  I didn't consider that.  Where it says "Name:" I tired typing in something like "/home/test.pdf" that didn't work at all.  The file didn't get saved anywhere.  That needs an answer as well.  Thanks for pointing that out.